# Prove that if $\lim_{n\to+\infty} a_n = +\infty$ then $\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} = +\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I have to prove a problem, I arrived to a solution but I don't know it is correct.

The problem:

Prove that if
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty} a_n = +\infty$$

Then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty} \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} = +\infty$$

I thought about doing this similarly to how you prove Ernesto Cesaro's theorem.

By definition

$$\forall M\gt0 \quad \exists n^*: \forall n \gt n^* \quad a_n > M $$

Now I have

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n^*-1}+a_{n^*}+...+a_n}{n}$$

The first part of the fraction can be replaced with

$$S=\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n^*-1}}{n}$$

And then I have all the terms next to $a_{n^*}$ greater than $M$

$$\frac{a_{n^*}+...+a_n}{n} \gt \frac{(n-n^*)M}{n} $$

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_{n^*-1}+a_{n^*}+...+a_n}{n}\gt S+\frac{(n-n^*)M}{n}$$

Then I choose $M^*$

$$M^*=S+\frac{(n-n^*)M}{n}$$

I have at the end that

$$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n} \gt M^*$$

You can choose whatever $M$ you want, so the problem is proved.

I don't really know if the proof is rigorous, I tried to use that path and I hope that there could be at least something decent in there.

In the case the proof is not valid, I ask you if you can give some tip on where to start to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost ended the problem. You can suppose that all the elements of the sequence are positive (if not it is enough to add some fixed positive constant to every element of the sequence), so $S>0$. So from what you said, for every $M>0$ you have $n^*$ such that for all $n>n^*$,

$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}\geq S+\frac{(n-n^*)}{n}\cdot M>\frac{(n-n^*)}{n}\cdot M,$

As $\frac{(n-n^*)}{n}$ tends to 1 when $n$ tends to infinity, there will be some $N$ such that if $n>N$, $\frac{(n-n^*)}{n}>\frac{M-1}{M}$. Thus $\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_N}{N}>\frac{N-n^*}{N}M>M-1$. As you can do this for all $M$, the result follows.

Comment: So we have $\frac{M-1}{M}$ that is a constant value one time M is set, and then we have n that goes to infinity so we can state $\frac{n-n^*}{n}\gt \frac{M-1}{M}$ and we are introducing N to use it in the definition of divergence of a sequence? 
Then we end up with $\forall M\gt 0 \quad \exists N : \forall n \gt N \quad b_n \gt M$ where the M is the M-1 of the ${a_n}$ sequence right?

Comment: Hi, I edited the answer to make the reasoning more clear (and also I realized in the end I wrote $n$ instead of $N$). What we do is we prove that $\forall M\gt 0 \quad \exists N : \forall n \gt N \quad b_n \gt M-1.\\$ This implies the definition of convergence to infinity:
$\forall O\gt 0 \quad \exists N : \forall n \gt N \quad b_n \gt O,\\$ picking $M=O+1$ in the previous definition.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, but pardon me, I got a little more confused. Can't we end the proof one time we said $\frac{n-n^*}{n}\gt \frac{M-1}{M}$, so as a consequence we get $\frac{(n-n^*)}{n}\cdot M \gt \frac{M-1}{M}\cdot M \gt M-1$ 
Edit: I guess the N was set so we can say that for every $n \gt N$ we have the property $b_n \gt M-1$.
And the N is sufficiently high to have:
$\frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_N}{N}>\frac{N-n^*}{N}M>M-1$

Comment: Yes, it´s as you say, for every $n>N$ we have that $b_n>M-1$ so the problem is solved, because M-1 can be as big as you want.

Answer (score 0):

The idea in general is kind of ok, but it is not clear enough. You don't want to choose $M^*$, it should be given to you. What you can do is to notice  that from
$$
\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n\geq S_n+ M-\frac{n^*}n\,M,
$$
you obtain

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}S_n+ M-\frac{n^*}n\,M=M.
$$
As you can do this for $M>0$,
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n=\infty
$$
and so
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}n=\infty.
$$

Comment: Unfortunately, we have never been taught about the liminf, so I can't fully understand the answer, I tried to search something on google, but I still have incomprehensions. 
Anyways, I thought about choosing $M^*$ to apply the definition of a divergent sequence to the sequence $b_n$ defined as $\frac{a_1+\cdots +a_n}{n}$, still I can't proceed that way?

Answer (score 0):

Good proof,but I think we can make it easier.
for arbitrary $G>0$,exist an $N\in{N^+}$,for every $n>N$,$|a_n|>G$
with this ,we can select some clever $G$,$N_1,N$,and prove it with inequality.
The proof is very close to the proof of Stolz theorem.